# Google Docs main activity: couldn't find address

Tags: android, apk, manifest, huawei-mobile-services

I am developing a Huawei custom Theme. I was trying to change some Google apps (Documents, Sheets and Slides) icons. So I used as address their package name e.g. com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.slides

Since it didn't work, I tried with some activities, found in the manifest file, but no one worked yet. (for example com.google.android.apps.editors.homescreen.HomescreenActivity, which is the first one that appears when I open Slides);

So the question is:
is there a way to identify which is the main activity, nay, which is the activity who defines app icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the main activity declares the following intent filters ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleFilters)) in order to indicate for the system that this activity is Main and is a launcher activity:

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityClassName">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was way simpler than I imagined! I don't know why I didn't notice intent filters before 